# The difference between setting <Assembly: CLSCompliant(False)> and related to CLS compliance compiler warnings in NoWarn

Tags: .net, vb.net, compiler-warnings, cls-compliant

When VB.NET assembly is CLS-sompliant and some types inside it are not, the compiler shows not CLS-compliant type warnings (codes 40025, 40026, 40027, 40028).
In case I know about this non-compliance and fine with it, I want to hide the warnings. It is possible to do it in two ways:
1. Edit the project file and add the warnings to `<NoWarn></NoWarn>` section.
2. Edit the AssemblyInfo and set `<Assembly: CLSCompliant(False)>`.

Does anyone know about the upsides, downsides and possible consequences of these two approaches?

Comment: What about leaving the *assembly* marked as `CLSCompliant(True)` but marking the individual non-compliant elements as `CLSCompliant(False)`?

Comment: This also can be done, any solution will work. I'd like to know about the difference between the solutions, maybe there are some which I'm not aware of.

Comment: CLS compliance was a .NET 1.x concern.  That was all over and done with in 2005, back when generics support got added (very non-compliant for many languages but not verboten) and remaining languages that required CLS compliant assemblies either got updated (VB.NET) or forgotten (J#).  It is meaningless today, any programmer knows how to write a bit of glue to bridge the gap if it is really necessary.  It never is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to hide warnings about CSL-compliancy, just use `<NoWarn/>` tags: it means that you don't care how CSL-compliancy of your code.

By using explicitly `<Assembly: CLSCompliant(True/False)>.`, you clearly take a decision about the design/architecture of your code.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I see it as well. Looks like there are no additional consequences, which is totally fine:).